# Drop Down Menu is pulling to the Right

Tags: html, css

Hello i have been activly coding a new menu for phpbb for my new forums with my community and i have only one issue, its bugging me so badly the problem i have is when i setup all the code it worked fine then when i added another drop down menu it started to well do this...

```
[.navbar2   {
    position: absolute; /* Ensures that the menu doesn’t affect other elements */
    border-radius: 4px 0;
    }
.navbar2 li     {   
    left: auto;
    display: inline;
    padding: 0 5px;
    float: left;  /* This lines up the menu items horizontally */
    list-style: none;  /* Removes the default styling (bullets) for the list */ 
}
.navbar2 li ul  {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
    display: none;  /* Hides the drop-down menu */
    color: #565656;
    min-width: 150px;
    max-height: 1000px;
    border-radius: 4px 0;
}       
.navbar2 li ul li {
    background-color: #fff;
    min-width: 150px;
    padding: 0 5px 0 20px;
}
.navbar2 li:hover ul    {
    display: block; /* Displays the drop-down box when the menu item is hovered over */ 
    border-radius: 4px;
} 

/*NAV 3*/

.navbar3    {
    border-radius: 4px 0;
    }
.navbar3 li     {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;  /* Removes the default styling (bullets) for the list */ 
}
.navbar3 li ul  {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
    min-width: 150px;
    display: none;  /* Hides the drop-down menu */
    color: #565656;
    float:right;
    margin-left:2px;
}       
.navbar3 ul li {
    background-color: #fff;
    min-width: 150px;
    padding: 0 5px 0 20px;
}
.navbar3 li:hover ul    {
    display: block; /* Displays the drop-down box when the menu item is hovered over */ 
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin-left:-10px;
    float:right;
    margin-left:2px;
}]
```

[dropdown bug 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ocxjZ.png)

[dropdown bug 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4gz8h.png)

Comment: Please provide a jsfiddle link or at least paste in your HTML as well as the CSS so that users can replicate the problem and better assist you

Answer (score 0):

After stuffing around with some off the float: left codes i found out the problem i had its all fixed

Code Provided here..

```
.navbar2    {
    position: absolute; /* Ensures that the menu doesn’t affect other elements */
    border-radius: 4px 0;
    }
.navbar2 li     {   
    left: auto;
    padding: 0 5px;
    list-style: none;  /* Removes the default styling (bullets) for the list */ 
}
.navbar2 li ul  {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
    display: none;  /* Hides the drop-down menu */
    color: #565656;
    min-width: 150px;
    max-height: 1000px;
    border-radius: 4px 0;
}       
.navbar2 li ul li {
    background-color: #fff;
    min-width: 150px;
}
.navbar2 li:hover ul    {
    display: block; /* Displays the drop-down box when the menu item is hovered over */ 
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin-left:-10px;
    float:right;
    margin-left:2px;
} 

/*NAV 3*/

.navbar3    {
    border-radius: 4px 0;
    }
.navbar3 li     {
    list-style: none;  /* Removes the default styling (bullets) for the list */ 
}
.navbar3 li ul  {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
    min-width: 150px;
    display: none;  /* Hides the drop-down menu */
    color: #565656;
    float:right;
    margin-left:2px;
}       
.navbar3 ul li {
    background-color: #fff;
    min-width: 150px;
    padding: 0 5px 0 20px;
}
.navbar3 li:hover ul    {
    display: block; /* Displays the drop-down box when the menu item is hovered over */ 
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin-left:-10px;
    float:right;
    margin-left:2px;
}
```